# Does Google authentication in firebase provide a default password when creating a user in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

Does Google authentication in Firebase provide a default password when creating users in the Firebase database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The purpose for using social authentication is to not using password. So you will not get any.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to **create** a Google Authentication user through Firebase. While you can sign in to Firebase Authentication **with** a Google Authentication user, you can't create new Google Authentication users through it.